# PostgreSQL 9.4 expand jsonb int array into table with row numbers

Tags: arrays, postgresql, row-number, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

Trying to wrap my head around postgresql 9.4 jsonb and would like some help figuring out how to do the following.

Given the following example jsonb:

```
‘{“name1” : value1, “name2” : value2, “name3” : [int1, int2, int3] }’::jsonb AS table1.column1
```

Wanted: Return the “name3” array only, as a table with a return signature of

```
TABLE( var_name varchar, var_value int, var_row_num int)
```

So the resulting data would look like this:

```
(‘name3’, int1, 1)
(‘name3’, int2, 2)
(‘name3’, int3, 3)
```

Assume the array could be any length except zero and 'name3' is guaranteed to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem (thanks, Bruno), but it seems like more code than should be necessary?

```
WITH x AS (SELECT 'name3' as aname, jsonb_array_elements(column1->'name3') AS some_value FROM table1)
SELECT x.*, row_number() OVER () FROM x;
```

Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json_array_elements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html) to unnest the `json array` that results from `column1->'name3'`

```
SELECT 'name3' ,json_array_elements(column1->'name3')
FROM table1;
```

results

```
(‘name3’, int1)
(‘name3’, int2)
(‘name3’, int3)
```

Comment: This works for json, but not for jsonb. It should be SELECT 'name3' , json_array_elements( (column1->'name3')::json) FROM table1;

Comment: It also does not get the row numbers of the array.